# replace \r\n with < br /> as text

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying for 2 hours to replace \r\n with < br/> but it seems to be impossible.
I don't know what i'm doing! Please help!

```
const text = '"Hello!\r\n\r\nThis is a dog!'

const checkText = str=> {
  const match = /\r|\n/.exec(text);
  if (match) {
    //return str.replace(/(?:\\[rn]|[\r\n]+)+/g, '<br/>');
    return str.replace('/r/n', '<br/>');
  }
  return str;
};
checkText(text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this:

```
text.replace(/\r\n/g, '<br/>');
```

Answer (score 2):

Covering all the possible new line character combinations.

```
String tmp = s.replaceAll("\r\n", "<br>"); // Windows
tmp = tmp.replaceAll("\r", "<br>");        // Old MAC
return tmp.replaceAll("\n", "<br>");       // Linux / UNIX
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
(text+ '').replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '$1<br/>$2');
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things wrong with your code:

1. `String.prototype.replace` only replaces the **first** occurrence of a string. You need to use a regex argument with the `/g` flag to replace *all* occurrences.
2. Escapes use a backslash, not a forward slash: Use `\r\n`, not `/r/n`.
3. `checkText` returns a `string`, but your call-site doesn't do anything with the returned string - it's just dropped. Strings are immutable in JavaScript.

I don't recommend using strings to hold HTML because it can (very easily) cause HTML-injection (including `<script>`-injection) attacks.

Instead, do one of the following:

- Use `String.prototype.split` and HTML-encode each `string` in the array and `join` with `"<br />"`.
- Add the string directly to the document with `.textContent` (don't use `innerText` anymore) and give the parent element the CSS style `whitespace: pre-wrap;`.

Comment: The text is comming fro the API and i'm using React. Just need to parse the string that's all.